# hibernate 4 jta webpshere

Tags: java, hibernate, websphere, jta

Does anyone have a good example of how to setup Wepsphere 8 using hibernate 4.2.   We are not using EJBs.

When using the following configuration in hibernate.properties

hibernate.transaction.jta.platform=org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform

With no other properties, we get the following message when doing a 2phase commit (database and MQ)

[11/27/13 17:30:20:330 EST] 00000024 LocalTranCoor W   WLTC0032W: One or more local transaction resources were rolled back during the cleanup of a LocalTransactionContainment.

If we change the hibernate.properties to the following

hibernate.transaction.factory_class=org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaTransactionFactory hibernate.transaction.jta.platform=org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform

We receive the following: 
 org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaTransaction afterAfterCompletion HHH000426: You should set hiberna
te.transaction.manager_lookup_class if cache is enabled

Which also causes:
[11/27/13 14:31:18:526 EST] 00000035 SystemErr     R org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not advance using next()
[11/27/13 14:31:18:527 EST] 00000035 SystemErr     R    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
[11/27/13 14:31:18:527 EST] 00000035 SystemErr     R    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)

Answer (score 1):

We found the answer. If we set set the factory_class to org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaTransactionFactory.  We are then bound by the JTA settings in webpshere which is timing out the transaction.